# Как вывести копейки без целочисленного нуля

Tags: c#, winforms

Должно выйти 12Р 35коп.
И желательно как можно меньше строк в коде. Заранее благодарю!

```
double n = 12.348;
var str = string.Format("{0,-6:C0}{1:f2} коп.",n,n%1);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

выводит:

```
$12   0.35 коп.
```

как сделать что бы выводило:

```
$12   35 коп.
```

?

Comment: не знаю кто минусил, но на самом деле вопрос хороший. Например я сходу вообще не понял как решать "правильно", хотя в принципе как-то и не сказать что глупый или что не "бывалый". А тут такому интересному вопросу 2 минуса влепили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Строки настраиваемых числовых форматов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

```cs
var str = string.Format("{0,-6:N0}{1:00} коп.", n, n * 100 % 100);
```

Или даже так

```cs
var str = $"{n,-6:N0}{n * 100 % 100:00} коп.";
```

```
12    35 коп.
```

Но вообще вывод валюты делается так

```cs
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
var str = $"{n:C2}";
```

Или для .NET 6 можно так

```cs
var str = string.Create(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"), $"{n:C2}");
```

```
12,35 ₽
```

Кстати `double n`, для валюты используйте `decimal`, иначе есть риск неточно провести валютные вычисления.